# Какие страницы лучше использовать для SEO

Tags: seo

Есть блог в котором очень много статей и они динамически формируются из БД, возник такой вопрос - как лучше формировать контент для поисковых роботов, динимически на php странице или статический на html и под каждую статью заморачиваться html файлом?

Comment: Делайте дополнительный вариант без аякса

Answer (score 1):

> Есть блог в котором очень много статей и они динамически формируются
>   из БД

Проверьте не является ли содержание вашего блога **[Автоматически созданным содержанием](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306)**, потому что это есть сигнал Гугл для спама и ручных действий.